# Java binarySearch can't find all characters

Tags: java, arrays

**Hi everyone, I created a sorted list of array but when I search for character W it's not found. What may be the problem.**

```
public class BinarySearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] nam = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','X','W','Y','Z'};

        char code;
        int pos;
        int bck = 0;
        while (bck == 0) {            
        
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the Alphabet: ");
        String str = sc.next();
        code = str.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        pos = Arrays.binarySearch(nam, code);
        if (pos >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Alphabet "+code+" is at position "+ ++pos);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Character not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check the order of the ABC again. 'X' comes after 'W'

Comment: Or just run `Arrays.sort(nam)` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Eran said in the comment, the problem is in your alphabet as it should be `'V','W','X'`.

Also you don't need `int bck = 0`, because you could just make the while loop like always loop, until you stop the program like this: `while(true)`.